# HTML5 Canvas putImageData, translate it, change Image

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas, transformation

I want to draw an image using a HTML5 canvas, translate the image and then change the image but keep the transformations I've made. Is this possible?

Here's some pseudo-code to illustrate my problem:

```
// initially draw an image and translate it
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.putImageData(someData, 0, 0);
context.translate(200, 10);


// then later somewhere else in code
// this should be drawn @ 200/10
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.putImageData(someOtherData, ?, ?);
```

I thought this would be possible by some save/restore calls but I did not succeed yet, so how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 11):

The problem here is that `putImageData` is not affected by the transformation matrix.

This is by the Spec's orders:

> The current path, transformation matrix, shadow attributes, global alpha, the clipping region, and global composition operator must not affect the getImageData() and putImageData() methods.

What you can do is `putImageData` to an in-memory canvas, and then

```
inMemCtx.putImageData(imgdata, 0, 0);
context.drawImage(inMemoryCanvas, x, y)
```

onto your regular canvas, and the translation will be applied to the drawImage call.

Comment: thank you guys. the problem is both approaches require to keep track of the x/y coordinates what I want to avoid. I would prefer a way in which all transformations I made are applied to the new image. I thought about getting the transformation matrix, setting the new image and apply the matrix to the canvas again but this is not possible right? sorry if my first post was misleading.

Comment: Is there some way , to create image from getDataImage then use  drawImage ??

Answer (score 0):

Put the image and its associated data in a custom data structure. For instance:

```
var obj = {
    imgData: someData,
    position: [0, 0],
    translate: function (x, y) {
        this.position[0] = x;
        this.position[1] = y;
    }
};
```

Now you can do successive updates to both imgData and its position. Use `obj.position[0]` and `obj.position[1]` as xy-coordinates when drawing.

```
obj.translate(200, 10);
```