# Is HTML canvas getImageData() Method affected by translate() Method?

Tags: html

In HTML5 Canvas, after calling translate(), does getImageData() return transformed image or not?

Comment: I don't think it is affected by the translation matrix. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11849114/html5-canvas-putimagedata-translate-it-change-image)

Comment: But it is not marked as the right answer, I want to see the exact proof.

Comment: It wasn't an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not affected by the translate() method. See the [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2015/REC-2dcontext-20151119/#pixel-manipulation) for details.

From the specification...

**"The current path, transformation matrix, shadow attributes, global alpha, the clipping region, and global composition operator must not affect the getImageData() and putImageData() methods."**

As previously advised, as per this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11849114/html5-canvas-putimagedata-translate-it-change-image).

Comment: Thanks!, it helped me a lot.